# Nested loop or equivalent

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to make a nested loop, I start with a simple loop and I would like make the same with differents data frames;

This work fine:

```
  set.seed(123)
    df1= data.frame(date= 1:10,
                vartre=rnorm(10, 30, 4),
                varpre=rnorm(10, 10, 5))

var=names(df1)

for(x in var ) {

plot(df1$date,df1[,x], type="l", main=x)

}
```

Now, I would like make the same with differents df´s, I tried to do with a nested loop but this dont work, example:

```
df2= data.frame(date= 1:10,
                varkyt=rnorm(10, 100, 40),
                varkdr=rnorm(10, 50, 5))

df3= data.frame(date= 1:10,
                varwer=rnorm(10, 300, 400),
                varpou=rnorm(10, 1000, 500))

dfs=c("df1", "df2", "df3")
for(i in dfs) {
var=names(i)
    for(x in var ) {
plot(i$date,i[,x], type="l", main=paste(i,x)))
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` (`mget` -returns the `list` of data.frame from the string identifiers) and plot

```
out <- lapply(mget(dfs), function(dat)  {
        var <- names(dat)[-1]
        lapply(var, function(x) plot(dat$date, dat[,x], type = "l",
           main = x))
     })
```

---

If we need to save it in a folder

```
path <- "path/to/folder/"
lapply(mget(dfs), function(dat)  {
        var <- names(dat)[-1]
        lapply(var, function(x) {

        png(filename=paste(path, "grafico", x,".png"))
          plot(dat$date, dat[,x], type = "l",
           main = x)
           dev.off()
           }
           )
     })
```

Comment: Thank! works great! just add a parentheses at  the end

Comment: I am getting problem when I add:  png(filename=paste("graph",i,x,".png"))                                  plot(dat$date, dat[,x], type = "l",
           main = x)), do you know why?

Comment: @Rodrigo What is  the error/issue.  as there are mutiple graphs, it may be better to call `pdf` and have it in a single pdf document with each graph in one of the pages

Comment: Sorry; Error: unexpected symbol in:
"png(filename=paste("graph",dat,x,".png"))
plot"

Comment: @Rodrigo.  What is `i` in the `png`.  In the code, we don't have `i`

Comment: I fix the last error (dat) now I just get: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
plot"
> > Error: unexpected '}' in " }"
>

Comment: @Rodrigo I think you need a `{}` i.e. `lapply(var, function(x) {png(filename = paste("graph", ....); plot(dat$date, .. })`

Comment: @Rodrigo Can you check if that is the issue

Comment: I did it but no fix the problem When I add a # :   #png(filename=paste("graph",dat,x,".png")) all work fine...

Comment: @Rodrigo I updated with the one that is working for me. Please check.  (change the `path` as your folder path